# Can I add array in class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript, and I tried to add array to my class to save some data:

```js
class ListOfItems {
  let listOfItems = []
  addItem(item) {
    listOfItems.push(item);
    console.log(listOfItems);
  }
}

const lOi = new ListOfItems();

lOi.addItem(10);
```

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I don't know if it is allowed to have variables in class. What can I do? I just want to have array of every added item.

Comment: I'm not sure the `let` is needed? Remove the `let`, then it can be accessed by `this.listOfItems`

Comment: create a constructor and initialize the array, then use this.listOfItems in the method to push

Comment: Introduce a constructor and initialise `this.listOfItems = []` inside of that.

Comment: Please at least read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes preferably a full javascript tutorial, that includes a section about classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write. I hope it worked for you.

```
class ListOfItems
{
  constructor(listOfItems) {
    this.listOfItems = [];
  }

  addItem(item)
  {
    this.listOfItems.push(item);
    console.log(this.listOfItems);
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but now I get error: listOfItems is not defined

Comment: @Anz, for console.log it should be `console.log(this.listOfItems)`

Answer (score 0):

You need [**constructor**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor) for creating and initializing an object of that class.

Instead of

```
let listOfItems = [];
```

Use `constructor` to initialize the array.

```
constructor(listOfItems) {
  this.listOfItems = [];
}
```

Code:

```js
class ListOfItems {
  constructor(listOfItems) {
    this.listOfItems = [];
  }

  addItem(item) {
    this.listOfItems.push(item);
    console.log(this.listOfItems);
  }
}

const lOi = new ListOfItems();

lOi.addItem(10);
lOi.addItem(20);
```